# The return value of the “logout” is the return value of his previous command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, logout

When I debug ssh, I find that the return value of "logout" is his previous command. for example,

```
[server1 ~] $ ssh root@server2

/* login server2 from server1 */

[root@server2 ~]# it's an bad command

-bash: it: command not found

[root@server2 ~]# echo $?

127

/* the return value is 127 */

[root@server2 ~]# it's an bad command

-bash: it: command not found

[root@server2 ~]# logout

Connection to server1 closed.

[server1 ~ ]$ echo $?

127

/* the return value is 127 too */
```

Can anyone tell me why the return value of logout is set this way?

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be obvious: for scripting.

Consider a typical thing to do without ssh, say:

```
grep -q crap file
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo something something
fi
```

If you suddenly need to perform grep on a remote machine, but want to act on the outcome on the local machine, you can just prefix the grep command with ssh invocation and everything will be fine.